# CN1 Android Build not Uploading

Tags: android, codenameone, android-build

I have an older (>2 yrs.) Android app that I need to resubmit to the Play Store.

The platform I am working on is Arch and I was using Eclipse for this application.

Uploading a newly generated apps works fine, I have tried it with the Initializr and  VsCode, and everything worked smoothly.

But when I try to upload my older app, using CodenameOne -> Send Android build from Eclipse, the upload is confirmed in the terminal, but the APK does not appear in my builds on the build site.

Any idea of how to get around this?

This is the console output:

---

```
Buildfile: /home/user/eclipse-workspace/A1_Test/build.xml

-cn1-compile-css:
        [java] Retina Scale: 1.0
        [java] Using stateful mode. Use -help flag to see options for new stateless mode.
        [java] Updating merge file /home/rainer/eclipse-workspace/A1_Test/css/theme.css.merged
        [java] Compiling /home/rainer/eclipse-workspace/A1_Test/css/theme.css.merged to /home/rainer/eclipse-workspace/A1_Test/src/theme.res
        [java] File has not changed since last compile.
        [java] CSS file successfully compiled.  /home/rainer/eclipse-workspace/A1_Test/src/theme.res

jar:
        [echo] Compile is forcing compliance to the supported API's/features for maximum device compatibility. This allows smaller
        [echo]          code size and wider device support
        [copy] Copying 14 files to /home/rainer/eclipse-workspace/A1_Test/build/tmp
       [javac] /home/rainer/eclipse-workspace/A1_Test/build.xml:105: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds
       [javac] Compiling 14 source files to /home/rainer/eclipse-workspace/A1_Test/build/tmp
       [javac] Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
       [javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
         [jar] Building jar: /home/rainer/eclipse-workspace/A1_Test/dist/A1_Test.jar
       [javac] /home/rainer/eclipse-workspace/A1_Test/build.xml:129: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 7 seconds
```

---

NEWLY ADDED OUTPUT WITH ERROR MESSAGE

---

```
CSS> [EDT] 0:0:0,162 - Exception: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError - /home/rainer/.codenameone/cef/lib/linux64/libjcef.so: libjawt.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
CSS> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /home/rainer/.codenameone/cef/lib/linux64/libjcef.so: libjawt.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
CSS>    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.load(Native Method)
CSS>    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries$NativeLibraryImpl.open(NativeLibraries.java:388)
CSS>    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.loadLibrary(NativeLibraries.java:232)
CSS>    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.loadLibrary(NativeLibraries.java:174)
CSS>    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2415)
CSS>    at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:818)
CSS>    at java.base/java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1989)
CSS>    at org.cef.SystemBootstrap$1.loadLibrary(SystemBootstrap.java:24)
CSS>    at org.cef.SystemBootstrap.loadLibrary(SystemBootstrap.java:36)
CSS>    at org.cef.CefApp.startup(CefApp.java:536)
CSS>    at com.codename1.impl.javase.cef.CEFBrowserComponent.create(CEFBrowserComponent.java:207)
CSS>    at com.codename1.impl.javase.cef.CEFBrowserComponent.create(CEFBrowserComponent.java:199)
CSS>    at com.codename1.impl.javase.cef.CEFBrowserComponent.create(CEFBrowserComponent.java:196)
CSS>    at com.codename1.impl.javase.cef.JavaCEFSEPort.createCEFBrowserComponent(JavaCEFSEPort.java:139)
CSS>    at com.codename1.impl.javase.cef.JavaCEFSEPort$2.run(JavaCEFSEPort.java:121)
CSS>    at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:308)
CSS>    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:771)
CSS>    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:722)
CSS>    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:716)
CSS>    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
CSS>    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
CSS>    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:741)
CSS>    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
CSS>    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
CSS>    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
CSS>    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
CSS>    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
CSS>    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
CSS> [EDT] 0:0:0,174 - Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException - Failed to create CEF browser
CSS> java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to create CEF browser
CSS>    at com.codename1.impl.javase.cef.JavaCEFSEPort.createCEFBrowserComponent(JavaCEFSEPort.java:133)
CSS>    at com.codename1.impl.javase.cef.JavaCEFSEPort.createBrowserComponent(JavaCEFSEPort.java:98)
CSS>    at com.codename1.ui.BrowserComponent$9.run(BrowserComponent.java:557)
CSS>    at com.codename1.ui.Display.processSerialCalls(Display.java:1338)
CSS>    at com.codename1.ui.Display.edtLoopImpl(Display.java:1280)
CSS>    at com.codename1.ui.Display.mainEDTLoop(Display.java:1162)
CSS>    at com.codename1.ui.RunnableWrapper.run(RunnableWrapper.java:120)
CSS>    at com.codename1.impl.CodenameOneThread.run(CodenameOneThread.java:176)
CSS> Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /home/rainer/.codenameone/cef/lib/linux64/libjcef.so: libjawt.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
CSS>    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.load(Native Method)
CSS>    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries$NativeLibraryImpl.open(NativeLibraries.java:388)
CSS>    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.loadLibrary(NativeLibraries.java:232)
CSS>    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.loadLibrary(NativeLibraries.java:174)
CSS>    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2415)
CSS>    at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:818)
CSS>    at java.base/java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1989)
CSS>    at org.cef.SystemBootstrap$1.loadLibrary(SystemBootstrap.java:24)
CSS>    at org.cef.SystemBootstrap.loadLibrary(SystemBootstrap.java:36)
CSS>    at org.cef.CefApp.startup(CefApp.java:536)
CSS>    at com.codename1.impl.javase.cef.CEFBrowserComponent.create(CEFBrowserComponent.java:207)
CSS>    at com.codename1.impl.javase.cef.CEFBrowserComponent.create(CEFBrowserComponent.java:199)
CSS>    at com.codename1.impl.javase.cef.CEFBrowserComponent.create(CEFBrowserComponent.java:196)
CSS>    at com.codename1.impl.javase.cef.JavaCEFSEPort.createCEFBrowserComponent(JavaCEFSEPort.java:139)
CSS>    at com.codename1.impl.javase.cef.JavaCEFSEPort$2.run(JavaCEFSEPort.java:121)
CSS>    at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:308)
CSS>    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:771)
CSS>    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:722)
CSS>    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:716)
CSS>    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
CSS>    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
CSS>    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:741)
CSS>    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
CSS>    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
CSS>    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
CSS>    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
CSS>    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
CSS>    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

Comment: This output looks like you just the jar target and not like the send Android build. Did you use the plugin to send the build? It's old but should still work. If the build isn't appearing it means there's a problem with the inter-connect. The Eclipse plugin is especially old so something there might have failed but I'm personally unaware of that. Is it possible you got a password prompt or a browser login window that you missed?

Comment: I have double checked everything today: internet connection, password, login, etc ... console output, etc. In fact, I have a second project that was  generated at about the same time in the past in Eclipse, and the other is uploading the build. I have tried these in parrallel today. To upload, I use the plugin from the CN1 context menu ... any idea where else I could look?

Comment: This is odd. I'm assuming both are uploading from the same machine so everything should work as authentication is global to the specific machine. Can you try sending a build from the command line using ant and the target `build-for-android-device` and see if that prints out additional information or fails differently?

Comment: never done this before ...  if you could put a complete command here, that would be helpful

Comment: Install the ant command line tool and run `ant build-for-android-device` when inside the project directory. Make sure that the current version of Java in the path is JDK 8 or 11.

Comment: Hi Shai, after a very busy week, only today I found time to look into this again. I don't know if there have been modifications to the upload process, but now the error message has changed. Oddly enough, only one of my apps is affected (the one I need/ Murphy's law :-) ) . I have added the terminal output above. Is there any easy solution to it?

Comment: In a nutshell, I can see two error messages : 'libjcef.so: libjawt.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory' and  'Failed to create CEF browser'

Comment: The best workaround for this is to convert the project to a Maven project. I think that's the simplest solution otherwise it's going down a Rabbit hole. But if this isn't an option the CEF problem probably means the library path is wrong. It's very hard to set on Ant. You can some potential known issues [here](https://github.com/shannah/codenameone-cef) based on your OS.

Comment: I will so as you recommend and generate a new maven project. Among VsCode, Eclipse, IntelliJ and NetBeans, is there an IDE you would favor? I have used VsCode recently  and I like it because it's swift.

Comment: I prefer IntelliJ but VSCode should work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

I figured the problem out after switching from VsCode to Eclipse, my favorite editor all along.

Each time I started a new project, I would be able to upload the Android build, but when I added resources, the upload wouldn't work.

Since there were no hints in the console output from VsCode, I started several approaches, like change folders, etc, but all in vain.

Then I figured I'd try it with Eclipse, and sure thing there I found the hint I needed. The console output pointed to the fact that I had `exceeded my data limit for the free plan`.

So the problem wasn't in any way related to the code or  the project settings.

Not sure if it is possible to have a better console output support in VsCode, since there are also many other hints missing that are present in Eclipse, like the exact line of code and the exact class of the error.